# Remove Width Attribute from Image Source with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, width

I have the following html.

```
<div class="matrix-itemFrame">
   <a href="/photos/landscape">
      <div style="background-image: url(images/landscape.JPG?width=400);" class="matrix-item"></div>
   </a>
</div>
```

This is from a Ning site so the mark up is what it is.
I want to remove the `?width=400` from the inline style so that the original image is displayed full res. 
Any help appreciated. 
THanks
RP

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what are you doing?

Comment: i think he just want to remove the `?width=400` from bg url

Comment: Ricardo is right, I just need to remove the ?width=400 from the bg url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('.matrix-item').each(function() {
    var bi = $(this).css('background-image');
    $(this).css('background-image', bi.replace(/\?width=\d+/, ''));
});
```

Comment: Sean, thanks, got it working on JSFiddle just not on my Ning site yet. This sets me on the right path though, so thanks!